# Error compiling Qt plugin project

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I've been trying to Create Qt Plugins, but to no much success so far. I'm following the Qt documentation, [**How to Create Qt Plugins**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html) on the Qt website.

The [**Plug & Paint Basic Tools Example**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaintplugins-basictools-example.html)  (*tools/plugandpaintplugins/basictools/basictools.pro*) compiles well. However, whenever I try to compile [**Plug & Paint Example**)*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-example.html) (*tools/plugandpaint/plugandpaint.pro*), I get the error:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lpnp_basictoolsd
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

even though I have a **libpnp_basictoolsd.a** in `plugandpaint/plugins`.

My non-compiling version of the official Qt example is [**HERE** (Plug-Paint-Example
) on GITHUB](https://github.com/TryRevilo/Plug-Paint-Example).

What could I be my problem? Thank you all in advance.

> > **Windows 7**
> >
> > Qt Creator 3.6.0
> >     Based on Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)
> >
> > Built on Dec 15 2015 01:01:38
> >
> > From revision b52c2f91f5

Answer (score 1):

maybe you shuld add libpnp_basictoolsd.a path to your project.

Comment: Hi @西蒙尼. Thanks for your response. I'm completely new to C++ / Qt. I'm not sure exactly how to go about that. Could you please illustrate.

Comment: 1.add .a
linux：LIBS += your_lib_path/your_lib
linux：LIBS += -L your_lib_path -lyour_lib
win32：LIBS += your_lib_path/your_lib
LIBS += -L lib/pcsc/ -lpcsclite
LIBS += lib/pcsc/libpcsclite.a
2.add headers
INCLUDEPATH += your_include_path
INCLUDEPATH += . /usr/local/include）

Comment: Did that. No success. Tried with the GitHub Repo I posted, but that is not working